# Get Username when committing to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've been building an application for almost a year now and ran into an issue when trying to use SQL Server triggers to write the users name to the database.  I had the database saved locally this whole time and recently moved it to our servers and have had to change my connection string and have included a general username and password in the connection string in my C# app.

In my tables and table triggers, I'm using the `SUSER_NAME` function to store who creates and edits a record. My problem is that now I've included a username in the connections string, all users that commit and update records fire the triggers using the username in the connection string rather than their network username.

I know how I could fix this, but it would require a lot of work to redefine my tables to get their environment username. I'm wondering if there could be a quicker fix where I could just change my default values and trigger update statements to use a function other than `SUSER_NAME()`.

Answer (score 0):

you have not specified if the application is a windows or a web app.

If it is a windows application, use integrated windows security to connect to sql server. After that you can use SUSER_NAME() function to get the username.

For web application there is no direct way of doing it.